# How to check file content in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a problem with my CSV files. I need to process a `sampleFile` to `resultFile`. And I write whole code for CSV with a header.

Let's say that csv looks (EVERY space in files below is \t or \t\t):

```
Head
Ver_info
number_Ver
data_source
Data.sam
Number Sample Val1   Val2 Val3
231    a1       a1    b1   c1
231    a2       a2    b2   c2
231    a3       a3    b3   c3
etc.
```

And... my code pick Ver_info, save as new variable (use it later as newFileName) and then data frame is loaded as all BELOW headers, and processing. So my result file looks:

```
231    a1e       a1    b1  
231    a2e       a2    b2  
231    a3e       a3    b3  
etc.
```

Now I have a problem with no header files eg.

```
231    a1       a1    b1   c1
231    a2       a2    b2   c2
231    a3       a3    b3   c3
```

How to check before the load (I'm loading a file by `pd.read_csv(file, skiprow = num)`, where `num` is a number of lines before headers, include) if a file has no header and content above?

Resume: One file started with content+header and then is data sep by \t. I have code for a process that. Another file has only data sep by \t without content and header. I need to check before processing that.
And... Content is not constant. :( 
I can't do something like: `if 'Head' in line = we have a header`

I tried with dataframe.shape coz I thought shape in second files will have many cols (wherein first case when I load the file I have only one) but in the second case I got one col too, coz file is separated by \t. But i cant separated file firs coz i got an error (first type of file have one col in first 9-12 rows, and next lines have few cols, and i got an error)

Have someone any idea how to deal with it?

Comment: if you know the number of columns, maybe just read the file line by line first and get the line where you get the number of delimiters ('\t') as you were expecting, and then set your skip_rows to that count.

Comment: You must first forget about pandas and open the file to read it as text to find whether it contains a header and if yes what it is. Then, you close it as process it normally with `pandas.read_csv` since you know what to skip.

Comment: Both tips are valuable to me. Thank you very much!